# Windows 7 stuck on welcome screen after installing VMware Workstation 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vmware-workstation

I have `Win 7 x64` and I have one account on it without any passwords.
I've just installed `VMware Workstation 7.0.1 Build 2276000`, after that Win 7 stuck on welcome screen and I have to click on the user image to continue.
Before that because I have just one account Win7 just showed welcome screen for a minute and then it went to Win7 desktop automatically, but now I have to click on my account image to continue.

**Something that I've done :** 
Start >> Run >> Msconfig 
Services Tab >> Checked `Hide all Microsoft Services`
Disabled all services except `Eset Services (Anti Virus)`

Unfortunately the problem haven't solved yet :(
How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Auto-Login Your Windows 7 User Account

1. Press the Windows key + R on your keyboard to launch the “Run” dialog box.
2. Type in `control userpasswords2`
3. Press Enter. The User Accounts window will display.
4. Uncheck the option “Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer”
5. Click “OK”
6. You will then be prompted to enter the current password and confirm it.
7. After doing so, you will no longer be prompted to enter your password upon login.

[Source of above info](http://on10.net/blogs/sarahintampa/Tip-Auto-Login-Your-Windows-7-User-Account/)

Comment: What is `userpasswords2` ?

Comment: BTW, my account is Administrator and it doesn't have a password.

Comment: got it, I had to type `control userpasswords2` :D My problem solved.